# I don't understand why is there a vertical line in my logistic regression graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, visualization, logistic-regression

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_df=pd.DataFrame([0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25,3.5,4,4.25,4.5,4.75,5,5.5])
y_df=pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1])
print()

#adding the column one since there is an extra theta value
x_df['intercept']=1

#converting to matrix
X = np.matrix(x_df.values)
print(X)
#
##converting the matrix y
y= np.matrix(y_df.values)
print(y)

#initialize theta
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))

def sigmoid(x):

    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))


def cost(x,y,theta):
    m = y.shape[0]
    h = sigmoid(x * theta.T)
    h1 = np.multiply(y,np.log(h))
    h2 = np.multiply(1- y,np.log(1-h))
    return -np.sum(h1+h2)/(1.0*m)

def gd(x,y,theta,alpha = 0.1,iter=10000):

    m = y.shape[0]

    for i in range(iter):
        h = sigmoid(x * theta.T)
        error = h-y
        update = np.dot(error.T,x)
        theta = theta - ( (alpha*update)/m )

    return theta,cost(x,y,theta),h

new_theta,new_cost,new_h=gd(X,y,theta)

print(np.ravel(new_h).T)

n=np.ravel(new_h).T

n=pd.DataFrame(n)
print(n)

plt.plot(x_df,y_df,'go',x_df,n,'bo')
```

I spent a lot of time trying to hard code the logistic regression in python 3, I believe the code it correct. After spending that much amount of time , when I began plotting the graph it turned out to be this!

[weird logistic regression graph in blue circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Kei.png)

Can someone please help me with the code? I am poor at visualizing the plots (hypothesis function vs X)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your plotting line to

```
plt.plot(x_df,y_df,'go', X[:, 0], new_h,'bo')
```

or

```
plt.plot(x_df,y_df,'go', x_df.ix[:, 0], n,'bo')
```

Your problem is that `x_df` has two columns, one is called `0`, the other is called `intercept` (which is all 1) and both are plotted as x-axis.